# How to Prove matrix $m \times m$ is invertible is equivalent to be $LI$ over $\mathbb{Z_{2}}$?

Tags: cryptanalysis

I came up with one problem that says that a $m \times m$ matrix is invertible is the same as to say that its rows are **LI** (linearly independent) over $\mathbb{Z_{2}}$.

First of all, I'd like to know how to prove it, in order to prove the following:

*Supposing $$z_{m+i} = \sum_{j = 0}^{m-1} c_jz_{i+j} \text{ mod 2}$$*

where $(z_1, z_2, ..., z_m)$ comprises the initialization vector. For $i \geq 1$, we define:

$$v_i = (z_i, ..., z_{i+m-1})$$, observing that $v_1,... ,v_m$ are the rows of the $m \times m$ matrix.

It asks to prove with these above informations:

*For any $i \geq 1$, $$v_{m+1} = \sum_{j = 0}^{m-1} c_jv_{i+j} \text{ mod 2}$$*

I've calculated $v_1 = (0, c_0z_1, ..., ), v_2 = (0, c_0z_2, c_0z_2 +c_1z_3, ...)$, however I don't see a way to know how to prove that for $\alpha_i \in \mathbb{R^*}$ that:

$$\alpha_1 v_1 + \alpha_2 v_2 + \alpha_3 v_3 + ... + \alpha_m v_m = 0$$

Comment: This is generally given as an exercise on a linear algebra course.

Comment: I didn't find one of such kind in my book of linear algebra.

Comment: $(\Rightarrow)$ what happens if you consider $M \times M^{-1} = Id$ modulo 2? 

$(\Leftarrow)$ can a zero linear combination appear when going from $\mathbb{Z}_2$ to $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Both conditions are equivalent to the kernel being null. I think the better proofs are high-level and don't rely on manipulating sums.

Comment: I think someone then, could migrate my question to mathexchange.